# Magento 2 how to get sorted children categories?

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.3

Can I get the **sorted children categories**? For example, I need sorted categories by the category name in the object `$subcats` in below code:

```
$subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
$subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: Does children category on same level?

Comment: you want to sort it alphabetically?

Comment: yes, need alphabetically sorted, and on same level.

Comment: Dhiren!, Abdus! is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: can you please help me on this? do you need any additional info?

Comment: check my answer i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory

```
    $test = $this->categoryCollection
        ->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('parent_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 'your_id')
        ->setOrder('name', 'ASC')
        ->load();
```